# Java If and Or Statement

Tags: java, if-statement

The following statement is working without any issues, but please can someone explain why, I was under the impression there should be an additional set of brackets before the `&&`?  However, even with the `()` missing it still works.

```
if(returnt.getInt("date", iLoop) == Util.getBusinessDate()
     && returnt.getInt("ins_type", iLoop) == Ref.getValue(SHM_USR_TABLES_ENUM.INSTRUMENTS_TABLE, "DEPO")
     || returnt.getInt("ins_type", iLoop) == Ref.getValue(SHM_USR_TABLES_ENUM.INSTRUMENTS_TABLE, " DEPO2"))
{...}
```

Comment: what check do you think is being made?

Comment: The logical AND operator has higher precedence than the logical OR operator has. The precedence determines in which order terms of your expression are evaluated.

Answer (score 4):

in short words your statement is like

```
if (A && B || C) {


1 1 1 => true
0 1 1 => true
0 0 1 => true
1 1 0 => false
```

the && binds "harder" then the "||" so it is evaluated first.

if you set the brackets like

```
if ((A && B) || C) {
```

the result is the same. at first the expression within bracktes (A && B) is evaluated and then the result is compared to C

if you set brackets like

```
if (A && (B || C)) {

1 1 1 => true
0 1 1 => false
0 0 1 => false
1 1 0 => true
```

in this case the expression within the bracket B || C is evaluated first, and then the && will be evaluated.

So... It depends om what do you want to express/check?

Comment: 0 &&  0 => 0. so 0 || 1 is 1?

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. I messed it up in my head. My bad. :)

Answer (score 4):

My old university professor used to say, perhaps rather inappropriately, that excess parentheses are for quiche eaters and for girls.

Learn your operator precedence tables by heart. Your code is equivalent to

```
if (((returnt.getInt("date", iLoop) == Util.getBusinessDate())
    && (returnt.getInt("ins_type", iLoop) == Ref.getValue(
      SHM_USR_TABLES_ENUM.INSTRUMENTS_TABLE, "DEPO")))
      || (returnt.getInt("ins_type", iLoop) == Ref.getValue(
        SHM_USR_TABLES_ENUM.INSTRUMENTS_TABLE, " DEPO2"))) {
```

*i.e.* `==` is evaluated first, then `&&`, then `||`. Note that the latter two are short-circutted, so evaluation stops once the result is known.

As you get more experienced you will find the version I've pasted up to be *considerably* more difficult to read.

Comment: " you will find the version I've pasted up to be considerably more difficult to read" - not if you add some whitespace and use intendation to highlight groups ;)

Comment: But don't you find `if (((` vulgar?

Comment: Yes, it looks nasty. I'd probably not use parantheses around `==` expressions though, they're understood in most cases. It's more likely devs have more problems with precendence of `&&` over `||` so you could use parantheses there.

Comment: The *only* place I allow excess parentheses is in the ternary conditional (its precedence always seems surprisingly low), and perhaps the modulus `%` if in non-mathematical code. If I were around in 1971, I'd have put `<<` and `>>` just above `*`, `/`, and `%`.

Comment: Hmm, that's probably a difference in style then ;) - I'd prefer `( A && B ) || ( C && D )`  over `A && B || C && D` especially on longer statements, most probably with a line break before or after `||`. After all it's meant to reduce the risk of misunderstanding and thus introducing subtle bugs but this of course depends on the people who are working on the code.

Answer (score 1):

So lets break it up

```
int val1 = returnt.getInt("date", iLoop);
int val2 = Util.getBusinessDate();
int val3 = returnt.getInt("ins_type", iLoop);
int val4 = Ref.getValue(SHM_USR_TABLES_ENUM.INSTRUMENTS_TABLE, "DEPO");
int val5 = returnt.getInt("ins_type", iLoop);
int val6 = Ref.getValue(SHM_USR_TABLES_ENUM.INSTRUMENTS_TABLE, " DEPO2");

if (val1 == val2 && val3 == val4 || val5 == val6) {.........
```

So the compiler compares the fist two i.e

```
val1 == val2
```

If and only if (because of the && ) this is true it will go to the next part which is

```
val3 == val4 || val5 == val6
```

Which means if either one of the two checks returns true your if statement will be true

The compiler will break the checks up into parts like this you would only need to add brackets to make this more readable.

Comment: So in a nutshell, it makes no difference if I add the additional brackets or not?

Comment: Not for your example no

Answer (score -2):

Because `==` has higher precedence than `&&`.

Comment: That's not even relevant, the question is about `&&` and `||`.

Comment: He wants to put brackets before `&&`. The only situation when he would want those brackets there would be when he doesn't understand that == is higher than &&

Answer (score -3):

The extra bracket you think are necessary, those are implicitely declare by Java ;)

Comment: Thank you to everyone for your comments.  So in a nutshell, if I add the extra bracket of not the code will still work as expected? I have tested with and without and it makes no difference.